# Tiered storage in Marklogic with HDFS as data directory

Tags: linux, windows, marklogic, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

I want to perform tiered storage in marklogic with HDFS as data directory. I am refering this (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/disk-storage#id_90620) document to create HDFS storage.

But the problem is this document have given setup process for Marklogic installed on Linux OS, but my Marklogic is installed in Windows OS and my HDFS is in Linux.

I don't find how to setup the HDFS as data directory for Marklogic installed on Windows OS.

Please help me out.

**My system details:**
Marklogic version 8.0 installed on Windows 7 (64 bit)
Hadoop Distribution: Hortonworks HDP 2.2 installed on Linux machine (64 bit).

Answer (score 3):

Accessing HDFS on Windows is not supported by MarkLogic.

Having said that, if you are just trying it out for dev purpose, you want to make sure that MarkLogic is started with the proper environment variables (JAVA_HOME, CLASSPATH).  You can reference the client bundle for HDFS HDP 2.2 for the required jars in your classpath:

http://developer.marklogic.com/download/binaries/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-hdp-8.0-3.tar.gz